# How to annotate a read-only array?

Tags: flowtype

In [flowtype](/questions/tagged/flowtype), an object can be made immutable by making it sealed and denoting properties to be covariant.

How to annotate a [flowtype](/questions/tagged/flowtype) parameter that cannot be manipulated?

Answer (score 3):

Use [`$ReadOnlyArray<T>`](https://github.com/facebook/flow/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=%24ReadOnlyArray&type=), e.g.

```
(values: $ReadOnlyArray<ValueType>) => {}
```

For more information, refer to the discussion in https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/3502#issuecomment-286259843.